# For Loop Outputs Same "ev" Values After Every Iteration

Tags: matlab, for-loop

this is a long script, but I feel that presenting all the information is important in order to understand what is going on. The main issue occurs when I try to calculate "ev" which is the energy of an electron in eV and "cs" which is a cross sectioanl area function based on eV, given the velocity components inputs. I made this so that velocity components randomly change at every time step, however, no matter what velocity is accepted by the system, the "ev" and "cs" matrices stay the same values. I cannot figure out why because when I tested each function without a for-loop, they run correctly and generate different values.

"ev" function that is referenced in the main script:

```
function [ev] = evfun(vx,vy,vz)

m_e = 9.11E-31; %Mass of electron
jtoev = 6.24E+18; %Joules to eV conversion

ev = jtoev*(0.5*(m_e)*(vx.^2+vy.^2+vz.^2));
%ev = log(nonfitev);

end
```

"cs" function that is referenced in main script"

```
function cs = crosecarc(ev)

nonfitcs = 34*exp(-((ev-500)/350)^2); %In units of 1E-16 cm^2
cs = nonfitcs*(1E-4); %Converts to 10^-16 m^2

end
```

Main Script:

```
filename = 'evtestsheet'; %Specify file name to print to
evmatsheet = 1; %Specify sheet in Excel File
evmatxlRange = 'G3'; %Specify evmat matrix start cell in Excel File
inputvelsheet = 1; %Specify sheet in Excel File
inputvelxlRange = 'D3'; %Specify inputvel matrix start cell in Excel File
inputpossheet = 1; %Specify sheet in Excel File
inputposxlRange = 'A3'; %Specify inputpos matrix start cell in Excel File

%Defining Space and Particle Density based on Pressure PV = nkT
mTorr = 500; %Define pressure in mTorr (From metter reading)
P = (mTorr/1000)*133.322; %mTorr to Pascal conversion to define pressure
k = 1.38E-23; %Boltzman Constant
T = 290; %Temperature in Kelvin. Converted from C  and @ room temp
N = 1; %Total number of particles
ChamTotalV = 1;


%Particle sweep volume is defined later because it depends on electron energy
tstep = 0.05E-8; %Defining time step
%modstep = 2*tstep; %Used when calculating volume swept since the DOE solver splits itself up into 3 times within each time step
tfin = 1.1E-8; %Defining final time
intspan = [0:tstep:tfin]; %Total time span
intspancol = intspan(:); %For Excel plotting purposes
[introw,intcol] = size(intspan);

%This section is just for generating matrices that will be populated later
tindex = [0:1:intcol-2];
tindexcol = tindex(:); %Purely for Excel plotting purposes
[tinrow,tincol] = size(tindex);
PCPmat = zeros(tincol,1);
choicemat = zeros(tincol,1);
colnewv = zeros(intcol,3);
Vsweepmat = zeros(intcol,1);
vmagmat = zeros(intcol,1);
evmat = zeros(intcol,1);
crossareamat = zeros(intcol,1);
inputpos = zeros(intcol,3);
inputvel = zeros(intcol,3);

%Test Initial Conditions
spart = [0.1 0.1 0.];
vpart = [-1.0585E+7 -1.0585E+7 0.5585E+7];

%for p = 1:1:size(s0parts) %particle count
    for t = 0:1:intcol-2; %complete time interval and time step

        [trow,tcol] = size(t);
        %spart = s0parts(p:p,1:3);
        %vpart = v0parts(p:p,1:3);

        %Defining relative position and velocity
        x = spart(1);
        y = spart(2);
        z = spart(3);
        vx = vpart(1);
        vy = vpart(2);
        vz = vpart(3);

        inputvel(t+1,1:3) = [vx vy vz];
        inputpos(t+1,1:3) = [x y z];

        r = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2 + z.^2);
        vmag = sqrt(vx.^2 + vy.^2 + vz.^2);

        ev = evfun(vx,vy,vz); %Plugs in velocity components of electron into the "evfun" function defined in seperate file to find energy in eV
        cs = crosecarc(ev); %Plugs in energy of electron into the "crosecarc" function defined in seperate file to find crossectional area
        crossarea = cs*4;
        Vsweep = crossarea*vmag*tstep; %Volume of space swept out by particle Vsweep = (area cross section)*(vmag)*(time step)
        %nden = N/ChamTotalV; %Number of particles per unit volume
        nden = 1/Vsweep; %Test line to force collision at every time step
        PCP = nden*Vsweep; %Probability of collision
        choice = rand(1); %Generate random number "choice" between 0 and 1

        %Populate the previously generated matrices with current values
        evmat(t+1,1) = ev;
        crossareamat(t+1,1) = crossarea;
        vmagmat(t+1,1) = vmag;
        Vsweepmat(t+1,1) = Vsweep;
        PCPmat(t+1,1) = PCP;
        choicemat(t+1,1) = choice;

        if choice <= PCP %If the choice by system is accepted within probability amplitude, then collision occurs
            %Assign new, velocity components based on energy prior to collision
            vxrand = 2*rand()-1; %Random # generation for component x between -1 and 1
            vyrand = 2*rand()-1; %Random # generation for component y between -1 and 1
            vzrand = 2*rand()-1; %Random # generation for component z between -1 and 1

            vmagrand = sqrt(vxrand.^2 + vyrand.^2 + vzrand.^2); %Normalize the randomly generated components
            vx = (vxrand/vmagrand)*vmag; %Multiply normalized, random x component by original velocity magnitude
            vy = (vyrand/vmagrand)*vmag; %Multiply normalized, random y component by original velocity magnitude
            vz = (vzrand/vmagrand)*vmag; %Multiply normalized, random z component by original velocity magnitude
        else
            newv = [0 0 0];
        end

        %Redfine the velocity and position components to reference on next if-loop run
        spart(1) = x;
        spart(2) = y;
        spart(3) = z;
        vpart(1) = vx;
        vpart(2) = vy;
        vpart(3) = vz;
        ev = [];
         %Clears ev matrix
    end

    xlswrite(filename,inputvel,inputvelsheet,inputvelxlRange)
xlswrite(filename,inputpos,inputpossheet,inputposxlRange)
    xlswrite(filename,evmat,evmatsheet,evmatxlRange)
```

Comment: In your loop you never actually use the returned value of `cs`. You also have several variables that are not defined including `crossarea`, `ChamTotalV`. It's also unclear to me how `spart` and `vpart` would be updated if you don't enter the block the defines `Wfor`. Is it possible that the mentioned variables are already in your workspace and unchanging? This would explain why your results are never updating. I recommend inserting a `clear all` at the start of your script and start debugging.

Comment: Sorry, the actual script is much longer and so when I was editing it down, some things got cut out. Everything is fixed now and defined properly and I tested this watered down script and it runs, however it does give the same issues still.

Comment: Also, the variables (vx, vy, vz) do change with each iteration.

Comment: `(vx, vy, vz)` will only change if `chance <= PCP`. In the example you gave the initial `PCP=~7e-5`, this gives an extremely small chance of these values ever changing unless you use a much longer time span. It also appears that your `(x,y,z)` values never update at the moment, I'm guessing they should be modified based on the current particle velocity.

Comment: (x,y,z) are present but they do not dictate (vx,vy,vz) here. They are independent. Yes, the if-else statement depends on the PCP value, however in this specific script, I forced the "PCP" value to always =1 to prove that velocity is changing but the "ev" function is not.

Comment: I've got it now. You are normalizing any changes to velocity such that, while the components of the velocity change, the speed does not. `ev` only depends on speed, not the direction. As a result every new velocity that you generate in this way will have the same `ev`.

Comment: Yes! I completely forgot the fact that energy is not changing which is why of course, the output of the ev function does not change either! Thank you!